# Mysql. date difference in months

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to write a query in order to get all the data whose date is greater than 11 months old or less than 12 months old. I have tried the query below which returns date difference in days. Is there any way I can check on months ??

```
$qb ->select("pj,DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_TIME(), pj.date) as dt)
    ->from("PrevJbs", "pj");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Mysql-function [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)

which can do it easier, but it operates PERIODS

```
$qb ->select("
        pj,
        PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIME(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(pj.date, '%Y%m')) AS dt
    ")
    ->from("PrevJbs", "pj");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is so easy to calculate in days.

But in months...  we can have 30,31,28...

Mysql (as i know) have no function to calculate diff in months.

So we should do it ourselves using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month.

Also we should remember that years can be different, we will use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year.

Lets try...

```
$qb ->select("
        pj,
        ((YEAR(CURRENT_TIME()) - YEAR(pj.date)) * 12 +
            IF ((MONTH(CURRENT_TIME()) >= MONTH(pj.date))
                MONTH(CURRENT_TIME()) - MONTH(pj.date),
                MONTH(CURRENT_TIME()) + 12 - MONTH(pj.date) 
            )
        ) as dt
    ")
    ->from("PrevJbs", "pj");
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in thinking that you just want to list all items except those between 12 and 11 months old?

Using DQL you could use..

```
return $qb
    ->select('pj')

    ->where($qb->expr()->lt('pj.date', ':lessThan'))
    ->setParameter('lessThan', new \DateTime('- 12 months'))

    ->orWhere($qb->expr()->gt('pj.date', ':greaterThan'))
    ->setParameter('greaterThan', new \DateTime('- 11 months'))

    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```